# How to use multiple tables in one model?

Tags: laravel, lumen

How to add multiple tables in one model without creating new model.

Is this standard practice to use same in laravel-lumen.

Or should I create 50 models to work on 50 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple table in one model. Each model is written for a specific table.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#introduction

Comment: If i am having 50 tables should i create 50 models in it?

Comment: Yes ! you need to create 50 models for your 50 tables.

Comment: Yes, but only as needed. You may have tables that don't actually need models, ie: you may not be interacting with them via Eloquent

Comment: @Chris Yes, You are right. But i think he wanted to interacting with table via Eloquent.

Comment: Yep, you are not wrong - it was more a *footnote against your answer

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses Eloquent Object Relational Mapper. So each model is like a class representation having methods to do query underneath.

You have to create 50 models if you have 50 tables, or at-least for the tables you are using in your application. TO save time, go for plugins like [this](https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator) which would generate eloquent models based on your database structure. Also check [another](https://github.com/reliese/laravel) plugin if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.
Each table should have their own model. But it isn't necessary all the times to make a model for each table. Investing some time on making model will help a lot in future work.